# 406 error during basic HTML update in rails (not jQuery, AJAX, or JSON)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Has anyone run into 406 errors when doing very basic form updates in rails? The object is updated but the redirect is failing. I've tried specifying the format as HTML as well as removing `respond_to do |format|` According to the logs it is updating as HTML `ItemsController#update as HTML`

I'm sure I'm just overlooking something silly, but have been beating my head against the wall trying to solve this. I'm not trying to update via ajax or access JSON. I've tried using the standard `respond_to do |format|` and specifying HTML as well as removing `respond_to do |format|` completely. The rest of the objects in the application can be edited and do not have this problem.

In routes

```
 resources :items
```

In the controller

```
def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
         redirect_to @item
    end
end
```

In the view

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>

     <%=f.text_field(:name)%>

     <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit %>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your update action also needs to handle the case where update_attributes is false. Something like,

```
def update
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
      redirect_to @item
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Comment: James, did that fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Shailen Tuli's answer, use

```
@item.update_attributes!(params[:item])
```

(notice the !)
It will generate an error if it cannot be saved.

406 means mostly: Rails has nothing to send back to the client, and in your case that happens when the saving fails.